# Simple Captcha or re Captcha for asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I would like to know if someone knows who to get a Captcha like the one on the website below. I like it a lot. It is simple and does not take any space. I like that the picture is transparent.

http://www.govanlaw.com/contact

Could someone point me in the right direction on how I could do this in ASP.NET. I am fairly new to web development.

Comment: It appears to be using [Really Simple CAPTCHA](http://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-captcha/) which is a plugin written in PHP.  You'd have to translate the code to ASP.NET, or perhaps find a similar library that can be customized to provide the same look and feel.  Library recommendations are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google's recaptcha .. here is the link [reCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)

Its free and it has all the instructions to include a recaptcha in several types of environments including asp.net

Here is the link which explains how to use the captcha in [asp.net](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/aspnet)

And you need a google account to get one.